# Programa en C. Un programa que despliegue todas las combinaciones de 5 archivos en 3 carpetas, el total de combinaciones son 243

Tags: c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Las diez primeras combinaciones de las 243, donde C1, representa la carpeta 1, C2, la carpeta 2, y C3 la carpeta 3, y los archivos están representados del 1 al 5: Como se muestra en la imagen.

llevo nueve semanas programando y me han pedido resolver este problema por recurrencia en el lenguaje c, no tengo idea de como resolverlo. Me podrían dar algunas ideas. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes que pensar en cada dígito como si fuese una rueda con 3 posiciones (de la 0 a la 2). Así, la rueda 1 tendrá que dar una vuelta completa para que la rueda 2 avance una posición ... cuando la rueda 2 de una vuelta completa avanzará la rueda 3 y así hasta que la 5 de una vuelta completa ... momento en el que debes parar.

Comment: En cada iteración (cada vez que la rueda 1 avanza una posición) debes verificar el estado de las 5 ruedas 3 veces (la primera vez te fijas en todas las que se encuentren en la posición 0 e imprimes el índice de dichas ruedas), repites otra vez pero ahora fijándote en las ruedas que se encuentran en la posición 1 y una vez más para sacar aquellas que se encuentren en la posición 2